# Add container-bound script to a Google Docs file programmatically

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-apps-script-addon

I am uploading files to Google Drive using the Drive REST API. I would like to have some default add-ons enabled on those files by default.
I was reading about container-bound scripts [here.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound)

But it is only possible to add container-bound script after opening the file in Google Docs UI. Is there any way to bind a script to a file while uploading or after uploading programmatically?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create the project of container-bound script type in Google Docs using Apps Script API. And when you have some scripts and you want to add the scripts in the project of container-bound script type, please do the following flow.

### 1. Create new project in Google Docs

You can create it using `Method: projects.create`.

#### Endpoint :

```
POST https://script.googleapis.com/v1/projects
```

#### Request body :

```
{
  "title": string, // project name
  "parentId": string, // file ID of Google Docs
}
```

### 2. Import scripts in created project

You can import the scripts in the created project using `Method: projects.updateContent`.

#### Endpoint :

```
PUT https://script.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{scriptId}/content
```

#### Request body :

```
{
  "files": [
    {
      object(File)
    }
  ],
}
```

#### Note :

- In order to use this API, please include `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.projects` in the scopes.

#### References :

- [Method: projects.create](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/create)
- [Method: projects.updateContent](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/updateContent)

If this was not what you want, I'm sorry.

Comment: @Asym Thank you for your response. Thank you, too.

Comment: Disclaimer: Apps Script API does not work with Service Accounts. Documentation for referance: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/concepts?hl=en